# Using CSS to locate elements in Selenium- appropriate style?

Tags: html, css, jsf, selenium, coding-style

I'm currently learning Selenium WebDriver as part of my internship. My supervisor wants me to learn it, set up a proof of concept and present on it so that they can start using it when they test their webapps (we use JSF, but it's not really relevant to the question).

The biggest issue I've had is locating elements with dynamic ID attributes. Since the ID's can change, there isn't a consistent way to identify an element. I've either used XPath, or pulled all the input elements and did further filtering to create a map of the elements I want.

I spoke with a friend of mine who does work in automation, who brought up creating empty CSS classes to identify elements. For example, given the tag:

```
<input id = "name"... class="... qa_name">
```

I could use a call to `driver.findElement.(By.cssSelector(".qa_name"))` to locate it. This would be incredibly convenient for a tester, since they'd have a deterministic way to locate an element on page.

Is there something wrong with this? I know it will work, and I'd like to recommend this as a practice, but my concerns are that:

1) Pages will take longer to load due to extra CSS that doesn't do anything appropriate to the page.

2) This isn't stylistically appropriate CSS, as it does nothing to the appearance of the page.

I asked a similar question on Programmers StackOverflow with no luck, so I'm hoping I can get an answer here. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel your pain. Adding classes to test elements probably isn't the best practice. Can you add `name` instead?

Another option with the dynamic IDs... is there some portion of the ID that is stable? You can use CSS Selectors to find the start of a string, the end of a string, or some portion of a string.

Suppose you have a `DIV` with a dynamic ID, e.g. `<div id="ct100_Text1_12345_Text2">` where 12345 is a dynamic number.

You could use a CSS Selector to locate the first part of the ID using

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[id^='ct100_Text1_']"));
```

You could use a CSS Selector to locate the last part of the ID using

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[id$='_Text2']"));
```

Or... you could use a CSS Selector to locate the middle part of the ID using

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[id*='_Text1_']"));
```

CSS Selectors are a powerful tool that I've only recently started to learn and use. They are worth the time to learn.

[CSS Selectors reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors)

Comment: This is the right way to go. And due to the findElement*S*, you can iterate over them if needed. And if your devs make sure they add id's to everything, the only thing that will be dynamic is an incrementing number in iterating components.

Comment: @JeffC There's almost always a stable part. What usually ends up happening is that the dev will name an ID, but JSF will re-generate the ID when it renders the page, and if one of the parent nodes are unnamed it inserts a random string at that point. 

I didn't realize you could search by tag name with By.cssSelector, let alone do substring searches. Thank you very much!

So, if you had a chain of nested divs, with the outermost div ID'd as "outer" and the innermost as "inner, the rendered ID for the innermost would look something like "outer:j_id134545254:inner".

Comment: @JeffC Forgot to mention, I'm not sure if I can use "name". On some of the rendered tags "name" matches "id". I'll look into this.